# pinch to zoom with magic mouse in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, multi-touch, mouse, bettertouchtool

I am unable to "pinch-to-zoom" on my magic mouse in mountain lion.  I am using better touch tool (but have tried disabling that and pinch-to-zoom still doesn't work).  In better touch tool under mouse > other gestures (zoom, etc.), it talks about changing sensitivities for normal predefined actions (which I think is what I want) and keyboard shortcuts (not what I want).  I have tried setting these higher and lower, but I still can't pinch-to-zoom with my magic mouse (like I can with my trackpad).

If anyone has any suggestions, I would much appreciate it!

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this app called MagicPrefs could help: http://magicprefs.com

It's expand standard capabilities of Magic Mouse.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how this product does solve the problem stated in the quesiton?

Comment: The options are there but doesn't seem to work very well :(